# Numerical solution of States matrix deviation

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

There is a system vector matrix ('S') defined as :

[image]

[image]

[image]

In this matrix `phi , alpha , beta , p ,r` and `q` can change with time and

all other indexed parameters are constant and positive.Also `phidot` mean

derivative of `phi` related to `time` and ... .

How can we calculate below derivative using numerical methods in matlab?

[image]

Comment: How would you do it with a pen and paper?

Comment: A matrix with size of 3*6 will obtain with a pen and paper

Comment: My point is, what don't you understand here? The mathematics, or how to write a Matlab implementation of the mathematics?